# Postgres showing 1 week before

Tags: sql, postgresql

this my table

```
tanggal    | product_name
2021-06-01   bag 1
2021-06-02   bag 5
2021-06-03   bag 8
2021-05-30   bag 11
2021-05-29   bag 12
2021-05-20   bag 13
2021-05-11   bag 14
```

this my query

```
select a.tanggal, a.product_name
FROM tbl_product a 
where current_date >= date_trunc('week', now()) 
order by a.tanggal desc
```

how to display 1 week before, starting from the current date?

Answer (score 1):

You need `tanggal` in the query.  If you want the most recent week:

```
select a.tanggal, a.product_name
from tbl_product a
where tanggal >= date_trunc('week', now())
order by a.p_dini_tgl_input desc;
```

If you want the week before that:

```
where tanggal < date_trunc('week', now()) and
      tanggal >= date_trunc('week', now()) - interval '7 day'
```

Comment: can the parameter use the current date ? e.g. date now() - date now()-interval  7 day ?
or date now - 7 day

Comment: @Jon . . . I would just use `CURRENT_DATE` or `now()::date`.  But yes, you can use those constructs as well.